# How to set the title of a browser page in Plone

Tags: plone

I'm trying to find how I can set the title of a browser:page. The main goal is to have it in the drop down "display" menu on my content type.

I have take a look in the code of CMFDynamicViewFTI. The only example there use browser:view and I don't know what it is, I have never seen browser:view. Is this the solution ? Does browser:view support customerize (The browser:view directive doesn't support the `template` parameter in zcml).

So is there anyway to set the title (as listed in the "display" menu) of a browser:page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `browser:page` is essentially just a browser:view directive with added support for templates. You can set a title using the zcml directive, just as you can for `browser:view`.

To set a title for the display menu, add the `menu` and `title` attributes to the `browser:page` directive:

```
menu="plone_displayviews"
title="title goes here"
```

You may also need to explicitly include the ZCML for plone.app.contentmenu first to make sure that the `plone_displayviews` menu is defined:

```
<include package="plone.app.contentmenu" />
```

Comment: If I add title in the zcml browser:page directive it raise Configuration error: ConfigurationError: If either menu or title are specified, they must both be specified.. If I add "plone_displayviews" it raises ConfigurationError: ('Invalid value for', 'menu', "ImportError: Couldn't import plone_displayviews, No module named plone_displayviews")

Comment: it works if you add     <include package="plone.app.contentmenu"/> and use menu="plone_displayviews"

Comment: I didn't need to <include package="plone.app.contentmenu"/> FWIW